# Merging two dataframe after running an optional variable through a python function on an SQL database. TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I get an error: "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable" when attempting this.  I'm having trouble trying to figure this out. I have the option to either pass or not pass a variable in a function that either extracts all the recrods from an SQL database or a single record from the SQL database.  The example below shows extracting a single record. I have two functions (see below). Once I have run the two functions I then want to merge the two results but thats when I get the error.  Each function in isolation works perfectly but its the merging that does not work.

```
def fundVaR(fundbhID=None):
    if fundbhID is None:
        fundVaR = pd.read_sql_query("""
        select *
        from vwExposure_VaR""",conn)
        fundVaR = pd.DataFrame(fundVaR, columns = ['ReportingDate','BaseHoldingID', 'BaseHoldingName','Strategy','VaR'])
        fundVaR = fundVaR.rename(columns={'ReportingDate': 'Date','BaseHoldingID': 'bhID','BaseHoldingName': 'bhName'})
        fundVaR = fundVaR.set_index('Date')
        return fundVaR
    else:
        fundVaR = pd.read_sql_query("""
        select *
        from vwExposure_VaR
        where BaseHoldingID=""" + str(fundbhID) + """ORDER by ReportingDate asc"""
        ,conn)
        fundVaR = pd.DataFrame(fundVaR, columns = ['ReportingDate','BaseHoldingID', 'BaseHoldingName','Strategy','VaR'])
        fundVaR = fundVaR.rename(columns={'ReportingDate': 'Date','BaseHoldingID': 'bhID','BaseHoldingName': 'bhName'})
        fundVaR = fundVaR.set_index('Date')
        return fundVaR

    
def fundAUM(fundbhID=None):
    if fundbhID is None:
        fundAUM = pd.read_sql_query("""
        select *
        from vwExposure_AUM""",conn)
        fundAUM = pd.DataFrame(fundAUM, columns = ['ReportingDate','BaseHoldingID', 'BaseHoldingName','Strategy','HoldingAUM','StrategyAUM','CompanyAUM'])
        fundAUM = fundAUM.rename(columns={'ReportingDate': 'Date', 'BaseHoldingID': 'bhID', 'BaseHoldingName': 'bhName'})
        fundAUM = fundAUM.set_index('Date')
        return fundAUM
    else:
        fundAUM = pd.read_sql_query("""
        select *
        from vwExposure_AUM
        where BaseHoldingID=""" + str(fundbhID) + """ORDER by ReportingDate asc"""
        ,conn) 
        fundAUM = pd.DataFrame(fundAUM, columns = ['ReportingDate','BaseHoldingID', 'BaseHoldingName','Strategy','HoldingAUM','StrategyAUM','CompanyAUM'])
        fundAUM = fundAUM.rename(columns={'ReportingDate': 'Date', 'BaseHoldingID': 'bhID', 'BaseHoldingName': 'bhName'})
        fundAUM = fundAUM.set_index('Date')
        return fundAUM

fundVaR = fundVaR(3127)
fundAUM = fundAUM(3127)

fundAUMVaR = pd.merge(fundVaR, fundAUM, on = ['Date','bhID','bhName','Strategy'],how = 'outer')
```

Thanks in advance!  Much appreciated

Comment: Which line is the reported error?

Comment: the last line:fundAUMVaR = pd.merge(fundVaR, fundAUM, on = ['Date','bhID','bhName','Strategy'],how = 'outer')

Comment: `fundVaR = fundVaR(3127)` and `fundAUM = fundAUM(3127)` are the issues. Use different names from function names. Also you can call `print(typeof(fundAUM)` and `print(typeof(fundVaR)` before the last the last line to ensure that they are DataFrame objects.